# Out of Memory issue in a gallery like application

Tags: android, out-of-memory, picasso, android-glide

I am trying to create an application which contains lots of Images from web services.I am using **Picasso** library for loading images into a gallery like fragment with **RecyclerView** having lazy load and passing list of URL's to slider activity with **ViewPager** i am dealing lot of images so after few slides it starts throwing **Out of Memory(OOM)** exception.I have tried with **Glide** its is stretching the image so i stick with Picasso.Tried a lot of methods like using large heap and allowing hardware access.Any method to **identify** and **handle** this issue would be helpful.

```
Picasso.with(context)
        .load(image.getImageURL())
        .memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE, MemoryPolicy.NO_STORE)
        .skipMemoryCache()
        .placeholder(R.drawable.poster_default)
        .error(R.drawable.poster_default)
        .into(mImageView);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agree with previous answer. You can also try use RGB_565 config. The image with this config two times smaller

```
Picasso picasso = new Picasso.Builder(this)
                .defaultBitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
                .build();
```

And set this instance to picasso

```
Picasso.setSingletonInstance(picasso);
```

The code snippet should be placed in onCreate method in android.app.Application class

Comment: I hope this reduced the issue.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Android uses bitmaps for images so that would mean adding large images will consume tons of memory. What I do in my projects is add `fit()` to the Picasso call to it so it will resize the image for me instead of loading it full size in memory.

Try something like below and see if it's fixed

```
 Picasso.with(context)
    .load(image.getImageURL())
    .fit()
    .centerCrop()
    .memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE, MemoryPolicy.NO_STORE)
    .skipMemoryCache()
    .placeholder(R.drawable.poster_default)
    .error(R.drawable.poster_default)
    .into(mImageView);
```